# How to use Babeltrace-log

Tags: linux, kernel, babeltrace

I want to transfer a txt log file into Common Trace Format (CTF) file. I found out that Babeltrace tool of lttng can transfer file between text format and CTF format. But I have got no clue how to do that. The command babeltrace-log, which can transfer txt file to CTF file, has the format:

***babeltrace-log [OPTIONS] OUTPUT, with only 1 option -t(timestamp).*** 
(http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/babeltrace-log.1.html)

I don't know how to give the input for babeltrace to transfer the file.

Would you please help me and give me some hints? There is little information online.

Thanks a lot,

Ailoiss

Answer (score 0):

As written in the manpage and by babeltrace --help :

"Convert for a text log (read from standard input) to CTF."

Typical use would be to pipe (using standard input) the result of one command into babeltrace-log:

dmesg | babeltrace-log -t outputfile.txt

Comment: babeltrace-log merely wraps the dmesg messages into instances of the 'string' event, which has a payload consisting of a single field 'str'.

With the -t option, the dmesg timestamps (seconds elapsed since machine start-up) are included in the output trace (which is otherwise timeless) as time elapsed since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UT, the Unix Epoch.